# Designing a PID Controller for Satellite Control

Tags: control-engineering, aerospace-engineering, pid-control, matlab

As an Aerospace Engineering Student, I have been trying to make a project of a PID Controller to control the attitude response of a satellite using the parameters from a project called Kufasat.

The parameters are described below (moments of inertia, mass, initial angular velocity, etc):

[image: Attitude Dynamics parameters]

Attitude Kinematics equations are also below:

[image: Attitude Kinematics equations and its results]

The idea is to design a PID controller to stabilize the angular motion of the satellite, reducing it to zero values. I have been trying to create some models in Matlab to insert the PID parameters, but all I got is divergences only. I feel like my model is unstable, or that I have been missing something here.

I have also tried to use the Aerospace Toolbox, but got no success at all. I also do not know if this toolbox would help me with this problem.
Furthermore, I have been thinking of State Space Formulation, but I have no idea of how I would organize all these variables in order to formulate the four matrices (A, B C and D), to make me able to apply a PID Control technique.

It is clear that I am lost, and I am even willing to pay someone to help me, as my advisor professor do not have enough time to help me build this.

Please, someone help me. I am desperate and need to finish this by the end of July.

Thank you so much.

Edit1:

Also, I have written a code in Matlab with all the calculations:

```
clear all

omega = [0.06 0.03 0.09];
I = [0.0547 0.0519 0.0574];
Kp = 0.008;
Kd = 0.08;
Ki = 10^-6;
phi_EAngle = [70; 40; 50]

Theta(1) = phi_EAngle(1)
Theta(2) = phi_EAngle(2)
Theta(3) = phi_EAngle(3)

R1 = [1 0 0; 0 cosd(Theta(1)) sind(Theta(1));0 -sind(Theta(1)) cosd(Theta(1))];
R2 = [cosd(Theta(2)) 0 -sind(Theta(2));0 1 0;sind(Theta(2)) 0 cosd(Theta(2))];
R3 = [cosd(Theta(3)) sind(Theta(3)) 0; -sind(Theta(3)) cosd(Theta(3)) 0;0 0 1];

R = R3*R2*R1

phi = acos((1/2)*(trace(R)-1))
a_x = (1/(2*sin(phi)))*(R'-R)

a(1) = a_x(3,2);
a(2) = a_x(1,3);
a(3) = a_x(2,1);
a = a'

q = a*sin(phi/2);
q_x = q'*q
q(4) = cos(phi/2)

phi_p = a'*omega';
a_p = 1/2*(a_x-cot((phi/2)*a_x*a_x))*omega'
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm just being obtuse right now, but it's been a while since I had to deal with classical mechanics. That said, I don't see in your writeup how do you actually exert control over the satellite, your torque input which would be governed through a PID. Is it the MATLAB  control signal? In that case it looks too big to work and I can understand the divergence, try lowering it.

Comment: On a different note, are you sure you want to do this with Euler angles? Mind the singularity, it can throw your code for a spin unless your orbit and attitude are particular enough to avoid it (doubtful).